# A class Adding manifest.xml - Android

Tags: android, xml, manifest

I have an activity class "MailActivity" which have methods , and I have a class too "Connection" which is not an activity class.

In the MailAcitivty class I am making operations with the return which is coming from the Connection class. And the Application use the Internet :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

And the Internet connection processes are happening into the Connection class.
But the application always fall into the catch after Connection return in the MailActivity class.

Am I need to add Connection class into the Manifes.xml? And If I need this, how can I do this?

Comment: Put your error log. I don't think that is an error of the manifest.

Comment: In android we dont add classes to manifeast file. It would be better if you can specify what error you are getting or what actually you need

Comment: It doesnt gave any error on logcat:S

Comment: Actually I think my main problem is ; I can not transition to Connection class from MailActivity on debug. If I can, I can fix this problem too. But I cant do that with debug. I create an object from Connection class into the MailActivity and call a method from Connection class with the object. But when I came on to the object line on the debug it fall into the catch